# Unable to Save Video to Camera Roll (Objective C)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, mp4

So I've been trying to accomplish this for quite some time now, but unfortunately none of the solutions posted on stack, or the ones I tried to write myself seem to work. I am building an application that allows users to take pictures and videos, and other users to save these down. I am using AWS services to save the content. Although the returned URL using NSLog, shows me the video when copy/pasting it to a browser, it refuses to save to the camera roll. Saving pictures however works fine.

So far I tried the following:

```
    -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
           NSURL *movieUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
           ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
           [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:movieUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
           if(error) {
            NSLog(@"CameraViewController: Error on saving movie : %@ {imagePickerController}", error);
         } else {
            NSLog(@"URL: %@", assetURL);
        }
     }];
  }
}
```

and also:

```
    if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(self.post.mediaUrl)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.post.mediaUrl, self, @selector(video:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),@selector(video:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Incompatible File apparently");
    }
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Updated on April 6, 2016 to make use of modern frameworks

Import the following in wherever you place this method:

```objectivec
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
@import Photos
```

Then call method as following:

```objectivec
[yourClass saveMedia:(*your image*) video:(*your video url*)]
```

Hope this helps people, feel free to comment with questions.

```objectivec
+ (void)saveMedia:(UIImage *)image video:(NSURL *)video_url {
    if(image) {
        if(!image) {
            return;
        }
    
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
        NSLog(@"%@", changeRequest.description);
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"saved down");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"something wrong");
        }
    }];
} else if (video_url) {
    if([video_url absoluteString].length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"source will be : %@", video_url.absoluteString);
    NSURL *sourceURL = video_url;
    
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[video_url absoluteString]]) {
        [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:video_url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
            
            if(assetURL) {
                NSLog(@"saved down");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"something wrong");
            }
        }];

    } else {
    
        NSURLSessionTask *download = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:sourceURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"error saving: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }
        
            NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
            NSURL *tempURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[sourceURL lastPathComponent]];
        
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location toURL:tempURL error:nil];
       
            [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:tempURL];
            
                NSLog(@"%@", changeRequest.description);
            } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if (success) {
                    NSLog(@"saved down");
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:tempURL error:nil];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"something wrong %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:tempURL error:nil];
                }
            }];
        }];
        [download resume];
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: crash in this line `NSURL *tempURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[sourceURL lastPathComponent]];`... My source url is -> `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1A12E654-19DB-4C2E-913B-93CA71B2F07C/tmp/RUDiVBDqGad6-SCVideo-Merged.mov` and last is -> `RUDiVBDqGad6-SCVideo-Merged.mov`.... Finally the crash is -> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:]: source URL is nil'
 *** First throw call stack:` can you help me?

Comment: @jose920405 sure thing, I wrote this a while ago but i'll post an update later today when i'm home!

Comment: thanks man for all, but i found the solution for other way, i needed `export the session` and later use the same `exportSession.outputUrl` and this way it could work

Comment: how to both file save video and image cameraroll objective c

Answer (score 1):

**In Objective - C**

Add this in .h/.m file

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

Save Video to Camera Roll:

```
 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                        [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:videoUrl];
                    }
                    completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                        if (success)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Video saved");
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                        }
                    }];
```